# SQL Server - the backup is not permitted because it is not online

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I'm new on this website and I hope I'm asking my first question in a proper way. I'm trying to backup a SQL Server database and I get the following error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: The backup of the file or filegroup "sysft_ FullTextCatalog" is not permitted because it is not online. BACKUP can be performed by using the FILEGROUP or FILE clauses to restrict the selection to include only online data. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

I googled it but couldn't find anything that helped. Does anyone has some ideas? Thanks.

Comment: http://support.servosity.com/entries/128944-The-backup-of-the-file-or-filegroup-sysft-FullTextCatalog-is-not-permitted-MS-SQL-database-backup-

Comment: Is your database offline? "Offline" means it is present on the disk, but not loaded into SQL Server's memory and not useable. If your db is online, then posting your T-SQL that does the backup would be helpful.

Comment: @RobertCalhoun - I've checked and the database is online..

Comment: @cdaaaaa: but the error message clearly says that the filegroup `sysft_FullTextCatalog` is **not online** - so it seems your fulltext catalog is not online and therefore the database cannot be backed up

Comment: Maybe you don't have a full-text index but your backup request is specifically asking to have it backed up? Anonymize your T-SQL and add it to your question.

Comment: @marc_s - I used this in order to find out either is online or not.. 

`IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
WHERE name = N'Database_Name' AND state_desc = 'ONLINE')
PRINT 'Database is online'
ELSE
PRINT 'Database is not online'`

More than that.. the message is incomplete. Before the uppercase "BACKUP", my message have an "OR" and starts like this "[...] OR BACKUP ..."